# Reactivity, isolation, and lists

Tags: meteor

There is something about reactivity I just don't understand, specifically with lists. My problem can be most easily modeled with the leaderboard example (`meteor --create example leaderboard`)

First, add this to the client side js (as is done at http://listtest.meteor.com/):

```js
Template.player.rendered = function () {
    console.log('Player rendered');
}
```

...and then watch the console as you run the app. When you switch the selected scientist, you'll notice that *each* player re-renders, even when it doesn't need to.

Thanks to some help on IRC, I discovered that sub-templating or #isolating the bottom portion of the main template like below (and at http://listtest2.meteor.com/ solves the inefficiency. In other words, when a different player is selected, only two players are now re-rendered: the newly selected and the deselected.

```html
<head>
  <title>Leaderboard</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="outer">
    {{> leaderboard}}
  </div>
</body>

<template name="leaderboard">
  <div class="leaderboard">
    {{#each players}}
      {{> player}}
    {{/each}}
  </div>
  {{#isolate}}
  {{#if selected_name}}
  <div class="details">
    <div class="name">{{selected_name}}</div>
    <input type="button" class="inc" value="Give 5 points" />
  </div>
  {{/if}}

  {{#unless selected_name}}
  <div class="none">Click a player to select</div>
  {{/unless}}
  {{/isolate}}
</template>

<template name="player">
  <div class="player {{selected}}">
    <span class="name">{{name}}</span>
    <span class="score">{{score}}</span>
  </div>
</template>
```

My question is this: why does isolating a different portion of a template cause a **different** subtemplate's behavior to change?

Thanks so much.

Comment: It might be that by stopping the parent template "leaderboard" from rendering by isolating the changes in "details" section you stop it from rendering all its subtemplates.  That is what is said [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13208254/728291) but there is no source for the information.  Very good question.

Comment: might be related: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1210

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explanation can be found in [meteor documenation](http://docs.meteor.com/#isolate):

> Reactivity isolation
>
> Each template runs as its own reactive computation. When the template
>   accesses a reactive data source, such as by calling Session.get or
>   making a database query, this establishes a data dependency that will
>   cause the whole template to be re-rendered when the data changes. This
>   means that the amount of re-rendering for a particular change is
>   affected by how you've divided your HTML into templates.
>
> Typically, the exact extent of re-rendering is not crucial, but if you
>   want more control, such as for performance reasons, you can use the
>   {{#isolate}}...{{/isolate}} helper. **Data dependencies established
>   inside an #isolate block are localized to the block and will not in
>   themselves cause the parent template to be re-rendered.** This block
>   helper essentially conveys the reactivity benefits you would get by
>   pulling the content out into a new sub-template.

Comment: Thanks! So if a parent template re-renders, its sub-templates will always be re-rendered as well?

Comment: If you use another block called **[#constant](http://docs.meteor.com/#constant)**, then code inside this block is not rerendered even if parent template is rerendered. In other case, you are right.