# Meteor - is isolate deprecated? What's in its place?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I am following this tutorial to incorporate Google Maps Javascript APIv3 into my application. It uses `isolate`, which throws this error:

```
Uncaught Error: No such template: isolate
```

This is not in the current documentation and Google is surprisingly unhelpful. The [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13155220/2317532) on [StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17986296/2317532) is outdated and probably not apply anymore. Apparently [Blaze has made `{{#constant}}` and `{{#isolate}}` obsolete](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Blaze#no-more-constant-isolate-or-preserve). **What has replaced `isolate`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`isolate` was a hack to work around the fact that spark would constantly re-render elements that it shouldn't. There is no replacement, because the blaze rendering engine simply does the right thing. Also see [this wiki](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Blaze#no-more-constant-isolate-or-preserve).

When reading an old tutorial, you should ignore any lines which contain `constant`, `isolate`, or `preserve`, though if it's that old you will likely encounter other problems which will be outside the scope of this answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've abandoned the tutorial and found a much simpler way to implement it. Thanks!